# VB.Net Project - Will not connect new Windows Form Datagridview to Database Table

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a VB.Net, VB project that I have been building over a few years in Visual Studio 2019 and 2022. I use it on two PC's, one to build it on and the other one for people to use. Using Microsoft SQL Server on both machines and identical databases I use various forms to update various tables.

It has been working fine in both environments until recently where I have created new forms with data-grid views to access several existing tables, they will not connect to the Db on one of the PC's, all the older forms work fine. I get an error that says the server was not found or accessible which cannot be the real issue?

I do not have any issues on the PC I use to build the project.

The only thing that has changed is the PC I build it on where I have updated it to Win 11 Pro on a x64-based PC. The other PC has Win 10 Pro on x64-based PC.

I'm not sure where to investigate, I've looked at the designer pages for the newer form but cannot see anything obvious. It can't be a connection issue as all the older forms will connect to the DB?

Any ideas would be much appreciated as I am baffled!

Comment: Show us the relevant code and show us the actual error message. This is not something we should have to ask for as it should be the first thing you provide for any question that involves code and error messages.

Comment: If the issue occurs when you call `Open` on a connection object, as it sounds like being the case, then the issue is with your connection string. If the error message tells you that the database you're trying to connect to cannot be found, it's because it cannot be found. There are various reasons that might be but the connection string is the place to start because that tells the system what to connect to and how to connect to it.

Comment: Hi jmcilhinney - there is no useful code to show you, I simply created a Windows Form and added a data grid view which is bound to a table in the DB, the only code which is automatically generated is to load the data into a table. ---  

Me.DT_Payment_RecordsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BoatLogDataSet.DT_Payment_Records). 

No other code is used.

Comment: The error message is...

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: If I ignore the message and load an older form it will connect fine.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code and error messages. No one should need to read the comments to understand all of the context of the question.

Comment: _The only thing that has changed..._: You won't believe how many times I've heard that one. After finding the issue, the response is usually _"Oh I forgot about that."_

Comment: Of course there's useful code to show. Data doesn't load from a database to a grid by magic. It's done by code. You need to show us that code. Also, the grid is irrelevant to this issue. The issue, based on the error message, is connecting to the database, which has nothing to do with the grid. You're not even getting as far as executing a query if you can't connect. As I have already suggested, the issue is with your connection string. The SQL Server instance you're trying to connect to either doesn't exist or cannot be accessed by your application. Show us the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, fortunately I managed to find the issue.

I had three connection settings saved in My Settings. Connection 1 being the one that I reset for the different environments at start-up. What had actually happened I had inadvertently set up new table adapters in my Dataset.xsd using one of the other connections, this resulted in it not being changed at start up in each environment.

If it helps others I'm happy to post the code that I use to do this.